# How do I use Discord-RPC with Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, discord, discord-rpc

I want to make a chrome extension which parses youtube/soundcloud/... pages and gets current song's name. Then it should update user's rich presence status in discord. Like a did it in python [there](https://github.com/TomoriBot/Tomori-Player/blob/master/player.py).

I have that one so far. Title already parsed, there's no problem. I have a problem with that code works. Because it doesn't work.

```js
const clientId = '605777168739598338';
const scopes = ['rpc', 'rpc.api'];

const client = new RPC.Client({ transport: 'websocket' });

client.connect();

function updatePresence(title, time, icon) {
    title = title.replace(/["]/g, "\\\"");
    client.setActivity({
        details: title,
        startTimestamp: time,
        largeImageKey: icon
    }, 9999)
}
```

I also tried raw websocket connection but I'm stupid..

UPD:
The code above is in content.js.

browser.js is a file copied from root of module [discord-rpc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-rpc) which i downloaded via npm.

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Tomori Player",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "browser_action": {
     "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["browser.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "ws://localhost:6463/*",
        "tabs",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ],
  "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": [
          "https://www.youtube.com/watch*",
          "https://youtube.com/watch*"
        ],
        "js": ["content.js"]
      }
    ]
}
```

P.S. I'm so sorry. I'm new in JS.

Comment: Extensions have different parts, each has different restrictions and capabilities. Add manifest.json to your question and specify which file contains the posted fragment of code.

Comment: Added. Pls, help me ^_^

Comment: Modern Chrome disallows cross-origin requests in content scripts, see the [official CORB explainer](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches) for an example of doing the request in the background script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a solution I found:

- Chrome Extension parses page and sends sockets to another app
- Another app on your PC gets these sockets and then sends RPC to Discord

> Timeraa#7947 (PreMiD dev): Discord will disconnect almost immediately if you connect with a browser, trust me i tried. You will need to have an application running in the background

So, you can use PreMiD and push up PreMiD's presences list or make your own app to do it.